# How to extract the vector from a rank-$1$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd, positive-semidefinite, hermitian-matrices

Given **Hermitian** and positive semidefinite rank-$1$ matrix ${\bf Z} \in \mathbb C^{N \times N}$, how to find vector $\mathbf z \in \mathbb C^{N \times 1}$ such that $\mathbf Z = \mathbf z \mathbf z^{H}$?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in general, e.g. for $N=1$ and $z=i$ we get $zz^H = 1$ and for $z=1$ we get the same result. You will only be able to get the absolute values of the components of $z$ by taking the square root of $Z_{ii} = e_i^T Z e_i$.

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z$ is an eigenvector of $Z$, i.e. $Z z = (z^H z) z = |z|^2 z$. However you can only find $z$ up to a complex multiplier of modulus $1$. So, $z e^{i \theta}$ also satisfies eigenvalue / eigenvector pair.

Comment: Actually, you can find it up to a norm 1 multiplicative constant: the diagonal entries of $Z$ are the moduli of the coefficients of $z$. This is the best you can get, since it's easy to see that if $\alpha$ has modulus 1, then $(\alpha z)(\alpha z)^H=\alpha\bar\alpha zz^H=zz^H$.

Comment: @tomasz Yes, I meant that and edited the answer. $\alpha$ is always has the form $e^{i \theta}$.

Comment: OK, but I think it's still unclear. For any complex $w$, $wz$ also has the same eigenvalue, but it's not a solution of $Z=zz^H$ if $w$ has a different modulus (and $z\ne 0$).

Comment: Yes because eigenvalue related to $wz$ must be $|z|^2$, which is only the case when $|w|=1$.

Comment: Also, $Zz=zz^Hz$.

Comment: $z^H z$ is a scalar.

Comment: Yes, it is. So?

Answer (score 0):

Such $z$ does not always exist. For example, if

$$
Z=
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2\end{bmatrix}
$$

and there exists $z=(z_1,z_2)^T$ such that $Z=zz^T$, then $1=z_1z_2=2$.

If $Z$ is an Hermitian semidefinite matrix, then such $z$ always exists.
In fact, there exists an orthonormalized basis in which the matrix $Z$ has a real-diagonal form. Since the rank of $Z$ is $1$, then
$$
S^{-1}ZS=\operatorname{diag}(t^2,0,\ldots,0),\ t\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Let $z'=(t,0,\ldots,0)^T$. Then $z=S^{-1}z'S$.

Comment: I have edited my question. If $\mathbf Z$ is hermitian semidefinite, how do we get $\mathbf z$?